# Boost.Python: Converters unavailable from standalone python script

Tags: python, boost, converters

The title may not be as explicit as I wish it would be but here is what I am trying to achieve:

Using Boost.Python, I expose a set of class/functions to Python in the typical `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyPythonModule)` macro from C++ that produces `MyPythonModule.pyd` after compilation. I can now invoke a python script from C++ and play around with `MyPythonModule` without any issue (eg. create objects, call methods and use my registered **converters**). FYI: the converter I'm refering to is a numpy.ndarray to cv::Mat converter.

This works fine, but when I try to write a standalone Python script that uses `MyPythonModule`, my converters are not available. I tried to expose the C++ method that performs the converter registration to Python without any luck.

If my explanation isn't clear enough, don't hesitate to ask questions in the comments.

Thanks a lot for your help / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... The prototype of my C++ function was taking `cv::Mat&` as argument and the converter was registered for `cv::Mat` without reference.

That was silly.